# Regular expression to match a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

How to write a regular expression to match a string if at least 3 characters from the start are matching?

Here is how my MySQL query looks right now -

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName REGEXP "^[a-zA-Z]{3}someString";
```

Comment: Do you want a PHP expression or a MySQL expression?

Comment: I need MySQL expression.

Comment: why would you not substr the required letters with php and do the *"Select * From Table Where coloumn LIKE '$string%'"* ??

Comment: Why substring when you could LEFT(string, 3)?

Comment: yeah Left is fine - use whichever is faster if that matters :) - I just gave another idea without using regular expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use CONCAT or alike with REGEX, it will fail. Easiest way to do it, is:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Test WHERE colb REGEXP "^'.substr($mystring,0,3).'"');
```

Another is:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE LEFT(colb, 3) LIKE "{$mystring}%"
```

Answer (score -3):

Please use jQuery and jqSQL plugin. Note that symbol $ must be escaped in SQL query with this plugin.